# I want to make a custom view that behaves like an actionsheet come up in an iPad app

Tags: ios, objective-c, view

I have the main View Controller, which is embedded in a Navigation Controller.

I want to make another view pop up and take up just the middle of the screen, so it basically looks like an action sheet. To make this view pop out, there is a button on the navigation bar (called "Unlock").

I made a new UIViewController, and gave it a new class called CustomModalViewController. Then I put a UIView inside this on the storyboard.

Am I on the right track? What should I do next? Should I embed this CustomModalViewController inside the original Navigation Controller? And perhaps then use this code somewhere:

```
- (void)showLoginView{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.5 animations:^{
    customModalView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 225, CustomModalView.frame.frame.size.width, CustomModalView.frame.frame.size.height);
    }];
}

- (void)hideLoginView{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.5 animations:^{
    customModalView.frame.frame=CGRectMake(0, 480, CustomModalView.frame.frame.size.width, CustomModalView.frame.frame.size.height);
    }];
}
```

I'm new to objective c and Xcode, and it's still weird to me how all of the files come together.

Answer (score 3):

`UIActionSheet` disables the remaining screen. I advice you to do the same. So your way using `UIViewController` subclass would be an appropriate way. You should place your action buttons in the bottom of your controller's view.

You can set a semi-transparent view `backgroundColor` to view of the `customViewController` to achieve some visuality like `UIActionSheet`. You can easily show a modal view controller like:

```
[self presentViewController:customViewController animated:YES completion:^{
    // do something when opened, if you need
}];
```

And hide like:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    // do something when closed, if you need
}];
```

As it can be seen, you don't have to deal with frames. In the manner of controlling, you can implement some delegate methods, something like `CustomViewControllerDelegate`in your main view controller, so you can be aware of what happened in your `customViewController`.

Comment: I don't understand. You're saying I dont have to do anything else, besides add the show/hide code you added?

Comment: You should give it a try. It is easier than you think. My code sample should do the trick.

Comment: Where do I put the code? In CustomModalViewController.m? And then I ctrl+click and drag from the "Unlock" button on the nav bar to the CustomModalViewController.h or something?

Comment: No, you will put your code in both view controllers. Place "Unlock" button in your main view controller. And when it is tapped (add an action to it via UIB), allocate your `customViewController`, become delegate of it (connect the `delegate` outlet in UIB), and `present` it using the first method in the sample code. You place another button (an action button) in your `customViewController`, and when it is tapped, call the delegate function. In the implementation of the delegate method, call `dismiss` method in the sample. I can provide you some sample code, if you cannot make it out.